# Fetch currency rate in C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very simple sounding winform task in my book. Using windows form. Fetch the latest currency rate in the text box.

```
1 USD = ??? INR
```

best solution to display converted currency I thought was to use Process method with a query string...

```
http://www.xe.com/ucc/convert.cgi?Amount=" + costTextBox.Text.ToString() + "&From=USD&To=INR"
```

But how to get and separate the value into the text box?

Comment: In the source of the page you have specified, it states "WARNING: Automated extraction of rates is prohibited under the Terms of Use." So, you could parse the value out of there, but clearly that is not advisable.

Comment: You can also query this in Google (1 USD = ? INR) and it'll come up before the results e.g (1 U.S. dollar = 55.2211607 Indian rupees)

Comment: hmmmmm right @James I thouhgt of it only bcoz that was the best thing I can think off... Now let me figure out shall I use google?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to scrap the value from the response from xe.com i would suggest to either purchase their services from [here](http://www.xe.com/dfs/product.php) or use this free [webservice](http://webservicex.com/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=2&WSID=10)

1. Add the wsdl as a service reference.
2. Create the SoapClient
3. Call the ConversionRate method.

```
var result = client.ConversionRate(CurrencyConverterService.Currency.USD,
                                   CurrencyConverterService.Currency.INR);
```

Comment: I would have purchased it if this was not my school book practice exercise :).......... Thx a lot let me check if I should add some kind of webservice in my winform (textbox).....

Comment: SoapClient can be added into Winfroms too??? Can't use PHP and not able to add soapcliet in C# WinForm.

Comment: did you try adding the service reference. Right click on the References folder and select "Add Service Reference". In the dialog that opens thereafter, add the url to the wsdl - http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Google Finance API](https://developers.google.com/finance/docs/2.0/reference), see the following function :

```
public static decimal Convert(decimal amount, string from, string to)
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();

            string url = string.Format("http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q={0}{1}=?{2}", amount, from.ToUpper(), to.ToUpper());

            string response = web.DownloadString(url);

            Regex regex = new Regex("rhs: \\\"(\\d*.\\d*)");
            Match match = regex.Match(response);

            return System.Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
```

Then you can use the function in this way :

```
decimal converted = Convert(3.25, "USD", "EUR");
```

Comment: Nice, are there any restrictions on the number of requests that can be made?

Comment: Not too easy for me to understand google api (java), or maybe I'm not getting the C# related anything in there...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Yahoo currency converter](http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter/):

This method will give you current rate:

```
    decimal getCurrencyRate(string currFrom, string currTo)
    {
        decimal result;
        using (WebClient c = new WebClient())
        {
            string data = c.DownloadString(string.Format("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}{1}=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv", currFrom, currTo));
            string rate = data.Split(',')[1];
            var style = NumberStyles.Number;
            var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            decimal.TryParse(rate, style, culture, out result);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And you use this way:

```
        //convert $50 to INR
        decimal val = 50.0M;
        //get rate
        decimal rate = getCurrencyRate("USD", "INR");
        //calculate value in INR
        decimal inrVal = val * rate;
```